# Update nested dictionary values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to update nested dictionary values from a pandas dataframe, but currently it updates all nested dictionaries, not only the one required. Here is my current code -

```
import pprint
import pandas as pd

update_dict = [
    [1, 10],
    [1, 30],
    [2, 20],
    [2, 40],
               ]

update_df = pd.DataFrame(update_dict, columns=['list_one', 'list_two'])

list_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_two = [10, 20, 30, 40]

dictionary = {}
sub_dictionary = dict.fromkeys(list_two, 0)
for item in list_one:
    dictionary[item] = sub_dictionary

for item in list_one:
    sub_df = update_df[update_df['list_one'] == item]
    sub_list = sorted(list(set(sub_df['list_two'].to_list())))

    for sub_item in sub_list:
        dictionary[item][sub_item] = 1
```

The original dictionary looks liek this -

```
{1: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 2: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 3: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 4: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 5: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0}}
```

Currently the output looks like this -

```
{1: {10: 1, 20: 1, 30: 1, 40: 1},
 2: {10: 1, 20: 1, 30: 1, 40: 1},
 3: {10: 1, 20: 1, 30: 1, 40: 1},
 4: {10: 1, 20: 1, 30: 1, 40: 1},
 5: {10: 1, 20: 1, 30: 1, 40: 1}}
```

I would like the output to look like this -

```
{1: {10: 1, 20: 0, 30: 1, 40: 0},
 2: {10: 0, 20: 1, 30: 0, 40: 1},
 3: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 4: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 5: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same *sub_dictionary*, just do:

```
dictionary = {}
for item in list_one:
    dictionary[item] = dict.fromkeys(list_two, 0)
```

**Output**

```
{1: {10: 1, 20: 0, 30: 1, 40: 0},
 2: {10: 0, 20: 1, 30: 0, 40: 1},
 3: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 4: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0},
 5: {10: 0, 20: 0, 30: 0, 40: 0}}
```

When you do:

```
dictionary = {}
sub_dictionary = dict.fromkeys(list_two, 0)
for item in list_one:
    dictionary[item] = sub_dictionary
```

All the values from *dictionary* will point to the same dictionary, so when you update any of the values, the change is reflected across all values.

The provided answer will create a new dictionary for every value.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done the trick. Much appreciated. Although I don't really understand why that works. Thanks Dani!

Comment: @scanerisable every value of *dictionary* (i.e *sub_dictionary*) is the same object not different objects